# UNION ALL query in Oracle results in an error

Tags: sql, oracle

I cannot figure why I am getting this error message in Oracle. Please see the error message below. I am using a UNION ALL and both queries are working (the top and bottom ones).

Also, both queries have the same headers. So, I am not sure why this union all is not working and getting an error message. I keep trying to figure it out but I am not getting anywhere.

Error Message

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
Error at Line: 13 Column: 23
```

Code

```
select a.ID1, a.ID2, cnt, a.*, b.*
from (
select t.*, 
count(distinct ID1) over(partition by ID2) cnt 
from TABLE1 t) a
, TABLE2 b 
where a.cnt > 1
and a.ID1=b.ID1 (+)
and (b.STATUS in ('A','L','P','S') 
or b.DATE1 >= TO_DATE('2018-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
order by a.ID2 asc
union all
select a.ID1, a.ID2, cnt, a.*, j.*
from (
select t.*, 
count(distinct ID1) over(partition by ID2) cnt 
from TABLE1 t) a
inner join TABLE2 j
on a.ID1=j.ID1
inner join SCHEMA.TABLE3 d
on j.ALTER_ID1=d.ALTER_ID1
where a.cnt > 1
order by a.ID2 asc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You order the overall result set, not each branch of the union; so you have to get rid of the first `order by` clause:

```
...
or b.DATE1 >= TO_DATE('2018-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
union all
select a.ID1, a.ID2, cnt, a.*, j.*
...
order by ID2 asc
```

This is mentioned [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/The-UNION-ALL-INTERSECT-MINUS-Operators.html):

> You cannot specify the *order_by_clause* in the subquery of these operators.

---

Incidentally, if you're supplying fixed dates you can use [date literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1), which are a bit less typing:

```
or b.DATE1 >= DATE '2018-01-01')
```

And as @Littlefoot pointed out, this order-by clause will throw "ORA-00960: ambiguous column naming in select list" because you have `a.ID1, a.ID2, ... a.*` which means the ID1 and ID2 columns will appear twice in the select list, and Oracle doesn't know which ID1 reference you mean (they're the same value here, but needn't be). It isn't good practice to use `.*` - much better to list the columns you actually need.

It's also a bad idea to mix ANSI joins (as in the second branch) with old-style joins (as in your first branch); you may be getting away with it here but it can confuse the optimiser, as well as anyone else looking at the code, and even this could break some day. You've used `(+)` but not consistently so that will act as an inner join anyway; but if you want an outer join then write it as a proper ANSI one.

Comment: Almost everything is fine, except that `a.*` along with `a.id2` is going to cause *ORA-00960: ambiguous column naming in select list*. That's not your mistake; `select` should contain column list anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try using order by only at the end of last query and remove it from the first one when doing the union all.