# SQL/PLSQL : compilation error on line number 2 -select statement (statement ignored), line before union all (SQL command not properly ended)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Am I missing declaration somewhere, the cursor exists in package body :-

```
CURSOR recipe_attributes_cur(p_recipe_id IN recipe_data.recipe_id%TYPE) IS
    SELECT t.attribute_name, t.attribute_value,
         CASE
             WHEN ra.enum_list IS NOT NULL 
             THEN (SELECT choice_str
                     FROM recipe_enums_v
                    WHERE enum_list = ra.enum_list)
                     -- AND choice_id = t.attribute_value)
             ELSE TO_CHAR(NULL)
           END AS enum_value,
           ra.datatype_id
    FROM table(acls_recipe.get_sic_attributes_value(p_recipe_id)) t, recipe_attributes ra
    where ra.attribute_name = t.attribute_name
    order by t.attribute_id
   Union All
    SELECT ra.attribute_name, rd.recipe_value_num AS attribute_value,
           CASE
             WHEN ra.enum_list IS NOT NULL
             THEN (SELECT choice_str
                     FROM recipe_enums_v
                    WHERE enum_list = ra.enum_list
                      AND choice_id = rd.recipe_value_num)
             ELSE TO_CHAR (NULL)
           END AS enum_value,
           ra.datatype_id
      FROM recipe_data rd, recipe r, recipe_attributes ra
     WHERE rd.recipe_id = r.recipe_id
       AND rd.attribute_id =ra.attribute_id
       AND r.recipe_id = p_recipe_id
       AND rd.period_end is null
       AND ( ra.attr_group IN ('REQUIRED','ABORT','SELECTION') OR
             (ra.attr_group IN ('LIMIT','INTERNAL') AND
              rd.is_default = c_false
             )
           )
       -- exclude disabled parameter...
       AND ra.flavor NOT IN ('DISABLED', 'HIST', 'LOCKED', 'VX_ONLY')
       --exclude default value 'not set'
       AND rd.recipe_value_num NOT IN (c_not_set, c_set_to_auto)
       --exclude purge recipe attributes for implant recipes
       AND NOT (ra.attribute_name = 'PURGE_TYPE' AND
                r.recipe_type_id = c_rt_implant)
    ORDER BY ra.attribute_id;
```

Comment: Remove the `order by` from the first branch of the union - which *is* the line before `union all`... [see this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60957283/266304).

Comment: Should we compile this listing in the mind? 1. Remove everything. 2. Add one statement/expression/operation at each iteration. 3. Repeat step 2 until the code works. 4. Investigate the reason why added code fails (by asking a question or checking syntax)