# SQL/PLSQL : Is this (given below) the correct way to call the function inside 'FROM clause' of a cursor query contained in package body:-

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsql-package

```
CURSOR recipe_attributes_cur(p_recipe_id IN recipe_data.recipe_id%TYPE) IS    

SELECT t.attribute_name, t.attribute_value,
     CASE
         WHEN ra.enum_list IS NOT NULL 
         THEN (SELECT choice_str
                 FROM recipe_enums_v
                WHERE enum_list = ra.enum_list
                  AND choice_id = rd.recipe_value_num)
         ELSE TO_CHAR (NULL)
       END AS enum_value,
       ra.datatype_id
***FROM table(acls_recipe.get_sic_attributes_value(p_recipe_id)) t***, recipe_attributes ra
where ra.attribute_name = t.attribute_name
order by  ra.attribute_id --t.attribute_name

UNION ALL
```

Comment: How is the function defined? Do you get an error when you try that? Or wrong results, or some other reason for asking?

Comment: @Alex Poole It returns table, This is how its defined :-

Function GET_SIC_ATTRIBUTES_VALUE (p_recipe_id IN NUMBER) RETURN RECIPE_VIEW_SET pipelined 
is  
   -----------------------
-------------------------
 for i in (
-------------------
) loop
         pipe row(RECIPE_VIEW_REC_TYPE(i.attribute_name, i.attribute_value, null , null));
       end loop;

Comment: It's not allowing me to write full function here in comment, "too many characters" it says

Comment: You should add information, particularly code, as an edit to the question - not as a comment.

Comment: Because When I am compiling package with just the function added to package body, it's giving no compilation error, after I add this calling part in cursor query it gives compilation error, feels like the FROM clause has some problem

Comment: Then include the full error you get in the question as well. We can't guess what you are seeing. Please include the type definitions as well.

Comment: Adding function in another question, not able to add here even with editing ques

Comment: Please remove irrelevant parts of the code (`case` expression, joins etc) and provide the definition of the function (or at least its signature and type definitions if it's not a scalar function). Function call is the same regardless of the place in the code: `function_name(arg1, arg2, arg3)`. For functions returning collections to be a row source - `from table(function_name(arg1,arg2,arg3)))`

Comment: Also from a previous question this is part of a package, so perhaps you are just seeing the generic 'created with compilation errors' message? If so you can do `show errors` in some clients, or query the `user_errors` view to see what those actual compilation errors are. And then include those in the question, if they don't give you enough information to fix the problem yourself.

Comment: The `UNION ALL` after `order by` is most likely the source of your error.

Comment: That illegal `order by` [was already discussed in your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73901633/266304)...

Comment: I've tried commenting the order by clause, still the same error persists :-

Comment: You have still not updated the question to tell us what error you are getting. Or the type and function definitions. We can't help you if you don't include the information you've been asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you can't declare the cursor dynamicaly using something like in your question. But, there is another, pretty similar, way to do it.
You could generate the Select statement dynamicaly inside your package function and use that statement as a reference cursor.
Here is a simple example of a testf2() function within a CMOD package:

```sql
FUNCTION testf2 (mWhat IN VarChar2) RETURN VarChar2 IS
    mySQL VarChar2(512);
    sq VarChar(1) := '''';  -- this is a single-quote character for mySQL string
    
    Begin
        mySQL := 'Select ' || sq || 'A' || sq || ' "A_LETTER", 1 "A_NUMBER" From ' || mWhat;
        RETURN mySQL;
    End testf2;
```

This function takes a VarChar2 parameter (it can be anything you need to generate your SQL) and returns generated Select statement. If the parammeter is 'DUAL' the function will return...

```sql
Select 'A' "A_LETTER", 1 "A_NUMBER" From DUAL
```

Now, to make it work get the Select statement generated by the function and use it as a reference cursor ...

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Declare
    c SYS_REFCURSOR;
    mySQL VarChar2(512) := CMOD.testf2('DUAL');
    c_letter VarChar2(1);
    c_number Number(1);
Begin 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(mySQL)
    --
    OPEN c FOR mySQL;
    FETCH c InTo c_letter, c_number;
    --
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c_letter || To_Char(c_number));
End;

--  R e s u l t :
--  anonymous block completed
--  Select 'A' "A_LETTER", 1 "A_NUMBER" From DUAL
--  A1
```

This way you can generate your own SQL - Open it as a reference cursor and loop through it to get your job done.
Regards...